# shorten webscraping results into .txt file

Tags: python

i'm trying to filter information i scraped from a website.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/fc-bayern-munchen/startseite/verein/27'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0)'}

res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

res.raise_for_status()

print(res.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

spieler = soup.select('.even') + soup.select ('.odd')

for spiel in spieler:
  print(spiel.text)
```

the return looks like this:

```
35Alexander NübelA. NübelTorwartAlexander Nübel30.09.1996 (24)8,00 Mio. €  

27David AlabaD. AlabaInnenverteidigerDavid Alaba24.06.1992 (28)65,00 Mio. €
```

how can I make this look nicer with spaces inbetween the words and delete duplicated names?

thanks

EDIT: i have found another website that deliveres the information I'm looking for in a better format.

Comment: Please add a minimum reproducible example showing us what code you have tried so far and what problem you are facing. Stack over flow is not a code writing service

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're just grabbing row text as a lump. For each row, iterate over the cells and extract information from each one then you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Please show the exact output you want and show an attempt at getting it. Thanks.